# C++ Quadratic Equation Not Coming Out As Expected

Tags: c++, formula, quadratic-programming

I want to make the quadratic equation in C++ using only `a`,`b`, and `c` as the variables, using mostly parenthesis, but i'm not getting the correct answers.

```
root1 = ((-1*b) + (std::sqrt((b*b) - (4*a*c)))) / 2*a;
root2 = ((-1*b) - (std::sqrt((b*b) - (4*a*c)))) / 2*a;
```

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] showing what values you're using and explaining your result and the correct result.

Comment: Another way to say `-1*b` is `-b`.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
root1 = ((-1*b) + (std::sqrt((b*b) - (4*a*c)))) / 2*a;
```

the `2*a` winds up dividing everything by 2 and then multiplying by `a`. Some brackets will fix that.

```
root1 = ((-1*b) + (std::sqrt((b*b) - (4*a*c)))) / (2*a);
```